# Pasting to vim in putty enters to visual mode

Tags: 14.04, putty

Trying to paste text to vim opened via putty by pressing right mouse button. That usually worked for me. But now pressing right button enters vim to visual mode. Why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> has this function: Enter in visual mode.

To paste you should use instead the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: PuTTY doesn't (and I don't think ever has) support Ctrl-V for paste (or Ctrl-C for copy etc.), there is too much chance of it clashing with a terminal escape code. Click and drag to select text copies it to the clipboard immediately, Right-click pastes it.

Answer (score 0):

For PuTTY (tested on PuTTY 0.76 connected to a Debian 11 host):

`Shift`+`RightMousebutton` pastes without going into visual mode